# BizTalk 2016/19: How to create Message to receive Access Token from Webservice with dynamic Sendport

Tags: wcf, dynamic, biztalk, send-port

```
Msg_Get_AccessToken = "";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(GUID) = ...;
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WebServiceHost) = "http://...";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.VariablePropertyMapping)= @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<BtsVariablePropertyMapping xmlns:xsi='http://www...' xmlns:xsd='http://www...'>
<Variable Name='var_GUID' PropertyName='GUID' PropertyNamespace='https://...'/>
</BtsVariablePropertyMapping">;
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.BindingType)="WCF-WebHTTP";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.SecurityMode)="Transport";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl)=@"<BtsHttpUrlMapping> <Operation Method='POST' Url='{var_GUID}'  /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.HttpHeaders) = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"+"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123&client_secret=3456&scope=https://...";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.SuppressMessageBodyForHttpVerbs)="POST";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.SecurityMode)="None";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType)="None";
Msg_Get_AccessToken(WCF.MaxReceivedMessageSize)=2147483647;
Msg_Get_AccessToken(BTS.RetryCount) = 5;
Msg_Get_AccessToken(BTS.RetryInterval) = 5;
Msg_Get_AccessToken(BTS.IsDynamicSend) = true;
P_GET_ACCESSTOKEN(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)=Msg_Get_AccessToken(WebServiceHost);
P_GET_ACCESSTOKEN(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType)="WCF-WebHttp";
```

This is not working! I don't know how to transfer the information

```
"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"+"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1234&client_secret=5678&scope=https://...";
```

to the dynamic send port

Does anyone know how this might be done for the dynamic wcf-http send port?

Comment: "It is not working" is not a good problem description.   What debugging have you done?  What error messages do you get?  Have you tried using Fiddler or Wireshark to inspect the payload?

Comment: What is the reason you are using a Dynamic Port?

Answer (score 0):

We get access token with a WCF-behavior. Is that possible for you? See: [Token behavior in BizTalk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/step-3d-enabling-biztalk-server-to-send-and-receive-messages-from-salesforce)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't add a WCF-Behavior to a Dynamic Port

Comment: Can you make it static, add the behavior, and make it dynamic as a first code line in the code above? sendport.IsDynamic = true? I think that's a possible "workaround". msg.Context.Promote(“IsDynamicSend”, “http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties&#8221;, true); See more on: https://jamescorbould.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/using-a-static-send-port-like-a-dynamic-send-port/

Comment: I expect that making it static is exactly what they need to do, which is why I questioned them trying to do it with a Dynamic port, no answer from them yet.  P.S. James Corbould is a colleague of mine,.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it static, add the behavior, and make it dynamic.

Comment: Now I wrote a C# method with Restsharp to get the token, that works

Comment: Then I wrote a similar C# method to test the URL with the token with Restsharp but I always recieve a NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object, do you have an idea why ?

Comment: I created a new question for this ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234007/biztalk-2019-using-c-sharp-restharp-methode-in-biztalk-throws-nullreferenceexc

Comment: @Martin Bring  I tried to do it with  WCF-behavior from the Salesforce Example but I only found the AuthEndpoint to get the Token, but where in this code I do set the URL I send with the Token ?

Comment: HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = null;       

            WebHeaderCollection headers = httpRequest.Headers;
            FetchOAuthToken();

            headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + this.token_.access_token);
            headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/jason");

            return null;

Comment: @BenjaminR, the destination URL is set as an URI in the dynamic send port.